# python pandas strange error when concat the return values of 'apply'

Tags: python, pandas

i have a strange python pandas problem, I have a data frame new_employees which contains forname and surname of 7 guys. I am trying to read from a HR database that contains some details for each person.

```
def read_a_row(row):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    return(pd.read_csv('/HRdatabase/%s/%s/logs/details.csv'%(row['forename'], row['surname']) ));                                                                                                    

output = new_employees.apply(read_a_row, axis=1)
```

somehow, when i execute above code, i got this error:

```
1798     raise ValueError("Shape of passed values is %s, indices imply %s" % (
1799             tuple(map(int, [tot_items] + list(block_shape))),
 -> 1800             tuple(map(int, [len(ax) for ax in axes]))))
1801 
1802 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7,), indices imply (7, 6)
```

does anyone have any insight where i got it wrong? if i don't let the read_a_row function return the csv_file, but rather print it, there is no error at all.

I think this is really strange.

Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: The apply function is trying to return a whole dataframe in your case. You can't really do that. You can use apply to map a column or a row of a frame to a row/column or scalar. Printing is fine, but that's no surprise...

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is basically a join. You want to join the tables with the names and the surnames of the employees with the rest of their details. What I would do, if I were you
is load the whole HR database in a dataframe and join it with the new_employees dataframe.

example (hr data dataframe, hr_df)

```
     name surname haircolor
0   Klark    Kent     black
1    Lois    Lane     brown
2   Peter  Parker     black
3  Poison     Ivy       red
```

new_df:

```
    name   surname
0   Peter  Parker
1  Poison     Ivy
```

Now you have two choices: 
If the dataframes have the same column names
you can do:

```
pd.merge(new_df,hr_df,on=["surname","name"])
```

else:

```
pd.merge(new_df,hr_df,left_on=["surname","name"],right_on=["surname","name"]) #change the column names
```

You should get the desired:

```
      name surname haircolor
0   Peter  Parker     black
1  Poison     Ivy       red
```